# Unreadable bean property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have this simple model class:

```
public class Foo {
    @ColumnName(value="PREVDATEI_ID", id=12)
    private Long prevDateiId;

    public Long getPrevDateiId() {
        return prevDateiId;
    }
    public void setPrevDateiId(Long prevDateiId) {
        this.prevDateiId = prevDateiId;
    }
}
```

When processing it I get this error message:

> 2018-11-21 18:03:15.517 ERROR 29277 --- [nio-8093-exec-9]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid property 'prevdateiId' of
>   bean class [bar.Foo]: Bean property 'prevdateiId' is not readable or
>   has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match
>   the parameter type of the setter?] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid property 'prevdateiId' of
>   bean class [bar.Foo]: Bean
>   property 'prevdateiId' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.getValue(BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.java:73)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

I don't see a reason why this does not work, because several other members of that class work flawlessly, for example:

```
@ColumnName(value="STATUS_ID", id=11)
private Long statusId;

public Long getStatusId() {
    return statusId;
}
public void setStatusId(Long statusId) {
    this.statusId = statusId;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _when processing it_? Processed how? Receiving it as a model attribute?

Comment: Essentially `prevdateiId` should be `prevDateiId`, to match your accessors.

Comment: When you say its working for STATUS_ID then it says that STATUS_ID field name becomes statusId so similarly PREVDATEI_ID becomes prevdateiId. So rename your getter/setter like setPrevdateiId and getPrevdateiId respectively.

Comment: Thanks @bittu, your suggestion would solve the issue but I would like to better understand *why* the two names differ. Spring JDBC uses a RowMapper and somehow is misled

Comment: I see no difference. STATUS_ID camelCase is statusId. PREVDATEI_ID -> prevdateiId.  It tries to find the getter method for these camelCase names.

Comment: I added appropriate getters and setters that override those created by Eclipse automatically and this solved the immediate problem. But I wait if someone can explain to me why this is happening before closing this question

Comment: I added appropriate getters and setters that override those created by Eclipse automatically and this solved the immediate problem. But I wait if someone can explain to me why this is happening before closing this question